# When did we first see a purple lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, lightsaber

I have often heard that the reason why Mace Windu's saber is purple is that Samuel L Jackson just really wanted a purple saber because he likes that color, and thus the purple lightsaber was born. However this much is for certain, that wasn't the first time we saw a purple saber because in the 1997 video game Dark Forces II there was a Dark Jedi who wielded a purple lightsaber. This got me wondering when was the first time a purple lightsaber appeared in any official Star Wars media (canon or otherwise)?

Comment: My recollection was that Mr. Jackson mostly just wanted to be able to tell where he was on the screen.  And purple was cool.

Comment: His lightsaber hilt also had inscribed on it, "Bad M*#&$#^$".

Answer (score 3):

Boc, the Dark Jedi in Dark Forces 2 that you mentioned is probably the first.

An'ya Kuro also wields a purple lightsaber, but her first appearence was the 1998 Star Wars: Republic: Vow of Justice, the year after Dark Forces 2 was released.

I'm unable to find any earlier purple lightsabers.

Answer (score 2):

Jaina Solo's lightsaber was purple in the book *Lightsabers* by Kevin J. Anderson and Rebecca Moesta published in 1996; it was the fourth book in the *Young Jedi Knights* series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is very nice, though you could improve it by [edit]ing in a quote from the book.